# Javascript - determining specific urls clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I have a survey in which there are 3 URLs (see HTML below) within the question.  We want to track which specific URLs are clicked rather than just a URL was clicked.  I have this code for that with the embedded data of clicked=0

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  jQuery('#extLink').click(function(event) {
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("clicked", "1");
    jQuery("#NextButton").click();
  });
});
```

But I can't figure out a good way to modify this to be able to know the specific URL clicked, since the jQuery is #extLink and really this code is only counting if something is clicked but not specifically what.

Any advice?

The HTML code is for each option in the survey question.

```
<div><a href="https://www.directrelief.org/" id="extLink" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Direct Relief</a> - Support for people affected by emergencies</div>

<div><a href="https://water.org/" id="extLink" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Water.org</a> - Provision of safe and accesible water</div>

<div><a href="https://www.feedingamerica.org/" id="extLink" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Feeding America</a> - Works on hunger relief</div>
```

Comment: Please add the HTML code block also

Comment: `this.href` will contain the URL of the link.

Comment: I don't see any modification in the second version of the code. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The id of each link should be unique (e.g., extLink1, extLink2, extLink3). id should always be unique on an html page.

Then instead of having to do a separate event handler for each, you can add class='extLink' to all the links. Then:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  jQuery('.extLink').click(function(event) {
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData(this.id+"_clicked", "1");
    jQuery("#NextButton").click();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

id needs to be unique for each element on page, to style elements together or fetch a group of them with javascript please use classes.

any way this code may solve your problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div><a href="https://www.directrelief.org/" class="extLink" id="extLink1" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Direct
            Relief</a> -
        Support for people affected by emergencies</div>

    <div><a href="https://water.org/" class="extLink" id="extLink2" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Water.org</a> -
        Provision of safe and
        accesible water</div>

    <div><a href="https://www.feedingamerica.org/" class="extLink" id="extLink3" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Feeding
            America</a> -
        Works on hunger relief</div>

    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.extLink').on('click', (e) => {
            console.log($(e.target).attr("id"))
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mention, don't reuse `id`s, instead use a `class`.

The easiest way to store data about an element is to just create a property on that element.

In jQuery, `this` in the callback function references the element itself, so here we just give `this` a property of `click_count` and then increment that every time the link is clicked.

```js
jQuery('.extLink').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //just for this example, remove for production
  this.click_count = (this.click_count ?? 0) + 1;
  //Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("clicked", this.click_count); //uncomment this for production
  jQuery(this).siblings('span').text(this.click_count); //remove this for production too
  jQuery('#NextButton').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a href="https://www.directrelief.org/" class="extLink" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Direct Relief</a> - <span>0</span> - Support for people affected by emergencies</div>
<div><a href="https://water.org/" class="extLink" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Water.org</a> - <span>0</span>  - Provision of safe and accesible water</div>
<div><a href="https://www.feedingamerica.org/" class="extLink" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Feeding America</a> - <span>0</span>  - Works on hunger relief</div>
```

Although the challenge with this approach for this scenario is that the client also has access to the element properties, so they could changed `click count` to whatever they want, which would have unintended consequences.

Since we're using jQuery, a great work around to this is to use the [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method. This allows us to store data with the element, with the benefit that the client has no access to it.

```js
jQuery('.extLink').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();  //just for this example, remove for production
  let $link = jQuery(this);
  
  $link.data('click_count', ($link.data('click_count') ?? 0) + 1);
  //Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("clicked", this.click_count); //uncomment this for production
  jQuery(this).siblings('span').text($link.data('click_count')); //remove this for production too
  jQuery('#NextButton').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a href="https://www.directrelief.org/" class="extLink" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Direct Relief</a> - <span>0</span> - Support for people affected by emergencies</div>
<div><a href="https://water.org/" class="extLink" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Water.org</a> - <span>0</span>  - Provision of safe and accesible water</div>
<div><a href="https://www.feedingamerica.org/" class="extLink" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Feeding America</a> - <span>0</span>  - Works on hunger relief</div>
```